# Items inside of container won't stay inside parent despite child having overflow set to "auto"

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I'm in a bit of a pickle. Been searching and testing this out for a while but can't seem to get it it work.

Here's what I've got so far:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

.box-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 150px;
  width: 49%;
  background-color: #FFDAC7;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
  <h3>Some other stuff</h3>
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
    <div class="box">9</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
  </div>
  <h5>Maybe a button here</h5>
</div>
```

Now, I would expect the "box-container" div to only occupy 100% of the available space and having the children be scrollable but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Seems like I'm missing something obvious.

Here's a pen for those who prefer that, btw: https://codepen.io/georgiosApo/pen/gORxJwb

Thanks a bunch in advance for any pointers!

// G

Comment: Just add `overflow-y: auto;` to `.container`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you `css` like this:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/avnufp84/5/)

Comment: It looks like, to keep it on the right-hand side, use `position: absolute; right: 0; width: 30%;`.

Comment: Yeah, maybe the position "fixed" is causing some issues here. Trying "absolute" instead but this is not really solving my issue. Now the whole container is scrolling, not only the box-container div that I was hoping for. Thanks though!

Comment: I didn't know that you only want `box-container` to be scrollable. Can you check this: https://jsfiddle.net/exypgv75/31/

Comment: Thanks for the help! This really pointed me in the right direction. Dang, this really bugged me for a while.
In my main code where I got this problem I had a child div inside of the sidebar that I wanted to have it's own children to overflow auto. This really didn't seem possible so I ended putting all the children in the top most container for it to work. Thanks. I'll mark this as the correct answer. If you have any more tips regarding nested children and overflow auto, please let me know. Cheers and thanks for your help once again!

Comment: Hello again @NenadMilosavljevic ! I made a new fiddle illustrating the problem with nested containers. Any idea why this isn't working? Although my problem is fixed it still bugs me a bit that I can't seem to really understand why this isn't working as I would expect: https://jsfiddle.net/y8bc6dw5/
Thanks a bunch once again!

Comment: Hey. It's because you did not give `height` to `box-container`. When you add `height`, then if the content is larger than it, the scroll will appear. Here is a working example:  https://jsfiddle.net/7o6u5dgv/